# How to serve Django admin media files on Bluehost

Tags: django

I have set up Django 1.3 onto my BlueHost account with Python 2.6 and it is working well except when I enter the admin area it is void of any css/formatting - all I get is text.  In my research I found that I need to set up the web server to 'serve' the static files, Django does not do this (except when using the Django development server).

I have made several attempts but no success...  Here are the current settings:

Settings.py:

```
ADMIN_MEDIA_PREFIX = '/static/admin/'
```

.htaccess:

```
AddHandler fcgid-script .fcgi
RewriteEngine On
Rewritebase /
RewriteRule ^(static/admin/.*)$ [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /django/test1/mysite.fcgi/$1 [QSA,L]
```

There is also a symlink at the projects static files ../static/admin/ to ../django/contrib/admin/media

You can see the resulting page at http://www.foreignlanguageflashcards.com/django/test1/admin/
Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With some help from http://blog.ruedaminute.com/2011/01/2011-installation-instructions-for-django-on-bluehost/ I was able to get it working.  I gave up on using symlinks and:

1. copied the admin media files from `/.local/lib/python2.6/site-packages/django/contrib/admin/media` to `http://www.foo.com/django/project/static/admin/media/`  (part of my problem earlier was confusing the django project directory with the public url directory)
2. edited settings.py to include: `ADMIN_MEDIA_PREFIX = '/django/project/static/admin/media/'`
3. cleaned up the htaccess to look like:

> ```
> AddHandler fcgid-script .fcgi
> RewriteEngine On
> Rewritebase /
> RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
> RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /django/project/mysite.fcgi/$1 [QSA,L]
> ```

4. If it helps, here is the fcgi script:

> ```
> #!/usr/bin/python2.6
> import sys, os
> ```

```
# Add a custom Python path.
sys.path.insert(0, "/home1/username/.local/lib/python2.6")
sys.path.insert(0, "/home1/username/django_projects")

# Switch to the directory of your project. (Optional.)
# os.chdir("/home1/username/django_projects/project") 

# Set the DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE environment variable.
os.environ['DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE'] = "project.settings"

from django.core.servers.fastcgi import runfastcgi
runfastcgi(method="threaded", daemonize="false")
```